# SSRS Subscription Update

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am trying on trigger a report subscription post a certain task completion. My logic uses a T-SQL code that updates the MatchData record on the Subscription Table on the ReportServer database. Doing so also updates the date and time record in the Report Subscription page.

[image]

However, that's not working as it ideally should. After some observations, I noticed that if and only if I click ok on the subscription page, to save the date and time of subscription, it works. I am sure, clicking ok triggers some flag that the data is now saved. Problem is, I am not able to locate which table it updates when I click ok in subscription page.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, there's a better way of doing this same activity:

http://sqlserverbiblog.wordpress.com/2010/03/11/manually-starting-a-report-subscription/#comments

Answer (score 0):

Great Question @Sharktooth!

One solution would be to create a Data Driven Subscription that runs every X minutes, X being the max acceptable delay from Task Completion to Subscription Delivery. For instance, if it is acceptable to send the Subscription up to 10 minutes after Task Completion, then set the Subscription to Run every 10 minutes.

Here is a link to a tutorial on Data Driven subscriptions: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169673.aspx

Let me know if I can explain further.

Comment: Ron, I have already considered the possibility of creating a data driven Subscription. But as you explained, running a subscription loop for x time interval will incur a CPU overhead which I want to avoid.